# Program no longer logs after Spring Boot's application context is closed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

This trivial Spring Boot program logs before Spring Boot is loaded, while application context is active and after it has been closed:

```
package test;

import java.lang.System.Logger;
import java.lang.System.Logger.Level;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Test
{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = System.getLogger(Test.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Before loading Spring Boot");
        try (var context = SpringApplication.run(Test.class))
        {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "While Spring Boot is running");
        }
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "After application context has been closed");
    }
}
```

This is the log produced:

```
mar 05, 2023 6:56:10 AM test.Test main
INFO: Before loading Spring Boot

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.3)

2023-03-05T06:56:10.582+01:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] test.Test                                : Starting Test using Java 17.0.2 with PID 15944 (C:\dev\git\tsv-product\tsv-java\tsv-bom\tsv-lib\tsv-kernel-bom\tsv-kernel-lib\tsv_test\target\classes started by Mirko in C:\dev\git\tsv-product\tsv-java\tsv-bom\tsv-lib\tsv-kernel-bom\tsv-kernel-lib\tsv_test)
2023-03-05T06:56:10.585+01:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] test.Test                                : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-03-05T06:56:11.107+01:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] test.Test                                : Started Test in 0.854 seconds (process running for 1.14)
2023-03-05T06:56:11.112+01:00  INFO 15944 --- [           main] test.Test                                : While Spring Boot is running
```

- As expected, before Spring Boot is loaded, the JDK's default logger (JUL) is invoked.
- As expected, while application context is running, the Spring Boot's default logger (Logback) is invoked.
- Unexpectedly, after application context has been closed, nothing is logged. I would expect at least JUL invocation...

My Maven is as simple as possible:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Is this a bug of Spring Boot?

Comment: use only one line `var context = SpringApplication.run(Test.class);` or `var context = SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);` , DO NOT WRAPPER `try`.

Comment: please use `https://start.spring.io/` create your first spring boot application.